# Mapping multiple values to a single value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mapping

I have a list of model_names which are supposed to be mapped to a specific manufacturer. Each manufacturer may manufacture multiple models. My goal is to map this model_name list to their respective manufacturer name in an efficient manner.

Here is an example to demonstrate my problem.

`model_name = ["Legion", "ROG", "Nitro", "TUF", "Predator"]`

Their manufacturer details are stored in a dict.

```
manufacturer_dict = {
"ASUS":["ROG","TUF"],
"ACER":["Predator","Nitro"],
"Lenovo":["Legion"]
}
```

I need the output to be a `manufacturer_list` which contains the name of the manufacturer who made the model.
In order to map the model_name to their respective manufacturer, I have used the below code.

```
manufacturer_list = []
for each_model in model_name:
    for key, value in manufacturer_dict.items():
        manufacturer = ""
        if each_model in value:
            manufacturer = key
            break
    manufacturer_list.append(manufacturer)
```

Another approach that I can use is to maintain a dict where the key is model_name and value is the manufacturer_name. Here the number of manufacturers and their products can be in the 10 - 100 values range.

I was wondering if there is a better method to tackle this issue

Comment: A few hundred models is trivial so invert your dictionary (key is model, value is manufacturer). The only potential issue arises if more than one manufacturer has an identical model name

Comment: Your question is not comprehensive enough to be answered, I tried to read it many times but still, I'm not getting it. So, please clarify what you want. Do you want the output to be manufacturer_list which will give the following output to your input model_name list?
output_manufacturer_name =  ['Lenovo', 'ASUS', 'ACER', 'ASUS', 'ACER']

Comment: CtrlZ The model name is unique to each customer for my use case.

@iihsan Yes, I want the output in the format similar to output_manufacturer_name list. I was wondering if the the above code I used can be simplified further. To be more pythonic

Comment: As for now, it's not possible to simplify your code further, because you do not tell us what "each_model" is supposed to be. Is it pseudocode ? Is each_model supposed to be a list of models ? Is it supposed to be one model but you want to evaluate them one by one ?

Comment: each_model is the value present in model_name list. Corrected the question

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to create a new dict in which each key is one model/sub-brand that has a unique value that's a manufacturer.

**How to associate each element of each value to their respective key :**

**With a double for loop :**

```
manufacturer_dict = {
"ASUS":["ROG","TUF"],
"ACER":["Predator","Nitro"],
"Lenovo":["Legion"]
}

models_dict = {}

for models, manufacturer in manufacturer_dict.items():
    for model in models:
        models_dict[model] = manufacturer
```

**With dict comprehension :**

```
models_dict = {
    model: manufacturer for manufacturer,
    models in manufacturer_dict.items() for model in models
    }


Output:  # {'ROG': 'ASUS', 'TUF': 'ASUS', 'Predator': 'ACER', 'Nitro': 'ACER', 'Legion': 'Lenovo'}
```

Comment: Yes, but the end result required is a list of the respective manufacturer name. Let me edit the question

Comment: I don't understand how a list containing only the manufacturer names is in any way mapped to the models.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the output you want but a way to deal with same model name for different manufacturer could be using `defaultdict` :

```py
from collections import defaultdict

model_name = ["Legion", "ROG", "Nitro", "TUF", "Predator"]

manufacturer_dict = {
"ASUS":["ROG","TUF"],
"ACER":["Predator","Nitro"],
"Lenovo":["Legion"],
"MSI":["Predator"]
}

res = defaultdict(list)

for manu, models in manufacturer_dict.items():
    for m in models:
        res[m].append(manu)
```

Eventually, if you need a list you can get it with

```py
[" or ".join(res[m]) for m in model_name]
```